# How can I terraform granting access to my Azure Active Directory Tenant

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Input: `client_id`, `subscription_id`, `resource-group-name`, .

Manual / command line steps:

1. Approving at

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code
```

2. Creating a new role (`az role definition create --output none --role-definition`)
3. Creating a role assignment (`az role assignment create`).

Steps 2-3 are pretty easy since I could leverage `azurerm` TF Provider and, more speficially, its `azurerm_role_definition` and `azurerm_role_assignment` [resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment) but I'm kinda confused about step #1.

Update: after googling it seems like step #1 is very similar to  [Enable Azure Active Directory in your App Service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can even get Terraform to interact with Azure/Azure AD resources you need to get Terraform to authenticate to it.

If you're running your Terraform code locally, the process is generally to authenticate using the Azure CLI - `az login` and then you provide the code shown by the CLI, to the authentication page.

If you want to do this non-interactively, the best practice is you'd need to get the Terraform code run on a machine that either has [Managed Identities](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity) enabled. Either a System-Assigned or a User-Assigned identity.

Another possible but less direct approach would be to use a Service Principal with a [Client Secret for Terraform to authenticate](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret). this is kinda like the link you provided for the App Service.

Try to follow the steps in those two links above as these are from Terraform and have all required steps to ensure you are able to set it up right.

Comment: right, let's assume I've initialized azurerm provider (see the last code snippet from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity), what's the data source / resource should I use for step #1?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question. Step1 is for authenticating to your provider...There are no data source or resource available/required for this. To use the 'msi' you will need to run your code in a machine that has a managed identity. When you do so, terraform will automatically authenticate to Azure while verifying if the identity has access etc. "By default, Terraform will use a well-known MSI endpoint to get the authentication token, which covers most use cases. " <- this basically says if you use `arm_use_msi` you're giving Terraform instructions to use an MSI to login

Comment: Hmm I got an impression that client_id in that link belongs to a 3rd party app, so even after I authenticate using my credentials, there's still an action to perform to allow 3rd party clientID to access **my** Azure AD.